# How do I generate a sequence of numbers divided by a constant?

Tags: r, seq

I want to generate a sequence (in R) of, for example, 6 numbers, where each number is the previous number divided by 2, for example 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125.

I tried 
`seq(4, 6, 0.5)`
but that adds 0.5, not multiply by. Is there a way to do this with the seq() command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can do the step as

```
4/2^(seq_len(6) - 1)
#[1] 4.000 2.000 1.000 0.500 0.250 0.125
```

---

Or with `seq`

```
4/2^(seq(0, 5, by = 1))
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
v1 <- 4
for(i in 2:6) v1 <- c(v1, v1[i-1]/2)
v1
#[1] 4.000 2.000 1.000 0.500 0.250 0.125
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
n <- 6
4/2^(0:n)
#[1] 4.0000 2.0000 1.0000 0.5000 0.2500 0.1250 0.0625
```

We can also use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, y) x/2, rep(4, n), accumulate = TRUE)
#[1] 4.000 2.000 1.000 0.500 0.250 0.125
```

which is similar to `purrr::accumulate`

```
purrr::accumulate(rep(4, n), ~.x/2)
```